# изменить value в теге input (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-forms

у меня есть форма, которая отправляется в гугл таблицу, возникла необходимость отправлять адрес страницы с которой посылается форма (станица динамическая).

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ovpSrmwaE8ednjqmVo4PxHZXHlCfbqdRvp355H8IS8Q/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="hidden_iframe" ng-submit="dissmisMtest()">
<input type="text" name="entry.1347629290" ng-value="urlina()" class="InputToGform" dir="auto" placeholder="ссылка" title="">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="&#1043;&#1086;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1086;" id="ss-submit" class="SendFormToGDocs myBtn">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

В контроллере функция urlina() выглядит так:

```
$scope.urlina = function () {
var a = "http://velesmebel.by/#" + $location.$$url;
console.log("location",a);
return a;
}
```

Однако value не изменяется, и не выводит адрес, помогите начинающему джаваскриптеру =) надеюсь на пнимание

Comment: А чем вас ng-model не устраивает?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#!

Comment: @IvanSoshnikov, только для вывода ngModel не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все решалось проще 
просто в value пишем {{b}},
а в контроллере прописываем 
$scope.b = "http://velesmebel.by/#" + $location.$$url;

Answer (score 2):

*по хорошему использовать ng-model

Скорее всего проблема в том, что ты не объявляешь аргумент $location при вызове контроллера либо url пустой.

Используй $location.absUrl() — тебе вернется полная ссылка.
Или делай проверку на то, что $location.$$url  существует и склеивай конечный ретёрн

Comment: если б урл просто пустой был, то вернулась бы вот эта строка: `"http://velesmebel.by/#"` кроме того не стоит использовать ng-model для вывода, так как этот атрибут подразумевает не только вывод, но и ввод

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, эти вещи нужно определять внутри контроллера:

```html
<form ng-controller="yourCtrl">
<input ng-value="yourCallback()">...</input>
</form>
```

...

```html
<script>
angular.module('yourModule', [])
.controller('yourCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.yourCallback = function() {
    return 'data';
  }
}]);
</script>
```

---

UPDATE:

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/BLRplex/zfznzzej/10/

Code:

```js
var module = angular.module('testModule', []);

module.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.yourCallback = function() { 
   return 'Value of the input';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testModule" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-value="yourCallback()" />
</body>
```

---

UPDATE:

**ngApp (ng-app):**

> **Используйте эту директиву для автозагрузки приложения.** Директива может быть использована только один раз в одном HTML документе. Директива обозначает корень приложения и обычно располагается в корне страницы.
>   В примере ниже, если бы директива ngApp не была помещена в элемент html, то приложение не скомпилировалось бы и {{ 1+2 }} не заменилось бы на 3.
>   **ngApp наиболее простой способ загрузки приложения.**

Подробнее здесь: http://angular.ru/api/ng.directive:ngApp

**ngController (ng-controller)**

> Директива ngController назначает поведение области видимости. Это ключевой аспект поддержки в Angular шаблона Модель-Вид-Контроллер.

Подробнее здесь: http://angular.ru/api/ng.directive:ngController

Comment: чем ваш пример отличается от кода в вопросе? А, все, нашел, стоит яснее сказать про атрибут `ng-controller`

Comment: Наличием контроллера. Недавно парни, с которыми я общался, как раз задавались подобным вопросом.

Comment: все-таки стоит сделать уточнение, что имелось именно внутри элемента с атрибутом `ng-controller`, а так же все это должно быть внутри элемента с атрибутом `ng-app`

Comment: Вот, я набрал то что писал в JSFiddle с маленькими уточнениями, все работает: https://jsfiddle.net/BLRplex/zfznzzej/10/